# Matlab/Octave with EC2

Tags: matlab, amazon-ec2, cloud, octave, distributed-computing

I'd like to use Matlab with EC2, its basically an embarrassing parallel problem so I don't necessarily need the parallel toolbox.

Reading the blog here:

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2008/11/parallel-comput.html

The link to the white paper, actually takes you to a webpage where it says that the service is only available in USA and Canada (I'm UK based) but that you can register your interest.

Moreover it seems there may be an issue with licences? If I have to buy a new license for each CPU its a non starter for me.

My program doesn't really use any big MATLAB function like lsqmin, so in theory it should be easily convertible to Octave (I think).

If using Matlab with EC2 is not possible for any of the reasons above can anyone tell me how to use Octave with EC2?

```
function [output]=DElambda(de,data,OF)

 P1=zeros(de.d,de.nP);
 Pu=zeros(de.d,de.nP);

 for i=1:de.d
 P1(i,:)=de.min(i,1)+(de.max(i,1)-de.min(i,1))*rand(de.nP,1);
 end


 P1(:,1:de.d)=diag(de.max);
 P1(:,de.d+1:2*de.d)=diag(de.min);


 for i=1:de.nP
 betas(:,i)=NSS_betas(P1(:,i),data);
 end

 Params=vertcat(betas,P1);

 Fbv=NaN(de.nG,1);
 Fbest=realmax;



 F=zeros(de.nP,1);
 P=zeros(de.nP,1);


for i=1:de.nP 

F(i)=OF(Params(:,i)',data);

P(i)=pen(P1(:,i),de,F(i));
F(i)=F(i)+P(i);


 end

 [Fbest indice] =min(F);
 xbest=Params(:,indice);


Col=1:de.nP; 

for g=1:de.nG
P0=P1;
rowS=randperm(de.nP)';
colS=randperm(4)';
RS=circshift(rowS,colS(1));
R1=circshift(rowS,colS(2));
R2=circshift(rowS,colS(3));
R3=circshift(rowS,colS(4));

%mutate
Pm=P0(:,R1)+de.F*(P0(:,R2)-P0(:,R3));
%extra mutation
if de.R>0 
    Pm=Pm+de.r*randn(de.d,de.nP);
end

%crossover
PmElements=rand(de.d,de.nP)<de.CR;
%mPv(MI)=mP(Mi);
if de.oneElementfromPm
   Row=unidrnd(de.d,1,de.nP);
   ExtraPmElements=sparse(Row,Col,1,de.d,de.nP);
   PmElements=PmElements|ExtraPmElements;
end

P0_Elements=~PmElements;
Pu(:,RS)=P0(:,RS).*P0_Elements+PmElements.*Pm;
%%%need to add penalty!!!!!!!!!!!!
%select vector to enter next generation

for i=1:de.nP
betasPu(:,i)=NSS_betas(Pu(:,i),data);
end



ParamsPu=vertcat(betasPu,Pu);
flag=0;
for i=1:de.nP
    %for j=1:dates
    %Ftemp=feval(OF,Pu(:,i)',data,j);
    Ftemp=OF(ParamsPu(:,i)',data);
    %end
    %Ftemp=OF(Pu(:,i),data);
    Ptemp=pen(Pu(:,i),de,F(i));
    Ftemp=Ftemp+Ptemp;

    if Ftemp<=F(i);
        P1(:,i)=Pu(:,i);
        F(i)=Ftemp;
        if Ftemp < Fbest
        Fbest=Ftemp; xbest=ParamsPu(:,i); flag=1;
        end
    else
        P1(:,i)=P0(:,i);
    end    
end

if flag
    Fbv(g)=Fbest;
end

end

output.Fbest=Fbest; output.xbest=xbest; output.Fbv=Fbv;
end



 function penVal=pen(mP,pso,vF)

minV=pso.min;
maxV=pso.max;
ww=pso.ww;

A=mP-maxV;
A=A+abs(A);

B=minV-mP;
B=B+abs(B);

C=ww*((mP(1,:)+mP(2,:))-abs(mP(1,:)+mP(2,:)));
penVal=ww*sum(A+B,1)*vF-C;


end
```

Comment: What's the nature of your problem? I mean, what do you want to calculate/compute?

Comment: I have an optimisation (using differential algorithm) that takes approx 8 hours to run on approx 2000 different data sets. The optimisation of each data set is completely independent and so can easily be split up. Sadly the optimisation is sensitive to the parameters used in the optimiser so I am faces with running this task multiple times to tune the optimiser.

Comment: I'm going to assume you're not allowed to share the code with me (NOT hte data, just the code)? I have a fair amount of experience improving Matlab code/converting to C++ where needed, especially in the context of optimization, and I haven't done it in a while and have been *aching* to get my hands dirty again :)

Comment: Rody happy for you to have a look, I have a C++ compiler (Visual studio 2008) so if you can convert it would be wonderful. I have someting running currently but once the machine unfreezes I'll post it.

Comment: Rody I've posted up the main function do you think you can convert it? Can PM you the ancillary functions _ data if you like.

Comment: Perhaps you can send me a ZIP of everything through e-mail. mylastname-at-gmail-dot-com.

Comment: will do Roddy but will have to be tomorrow now thanks Hugh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One idea that doesn't require additional licenses would be to deploy the [MATLAB Compiler Runtime](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/index.html) (MCR) on your EC2 instances. Then use the [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/index.html) to create executables of your code and run them on those EC2 instances.

> The MCR is provided with MATLAB Compiler for distribution with your
>   application and can be deployed royalty-free.

If you want to take this approach further, consider running a local job-queue that distributes work across available EC2 instances. [This](http://noisyaccumulation.blogspot.de/2010/09/using-amazon-ec2-to-speed-up-matlab.html) seems to be a nice write-up on how to do so.